# Numeric variable 'does not correspond to the value it prints, when used in functions in R

Tags: r, variables

First of all, I was very unsure what to call this question. I have wrestled with the problem for hours, that several of my numerical variables when used in a function seems like they have another value than when I print them.

The problem started with the fact that I couldn't properly refer to my columns in a data.frame. Then, when I tested deeper to see what the problem I found problems similar to the one below:

```
> rep(0, 9)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> start.time
[1] 9
> rep(0, start.time)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Shouldn't these two vector include exactly the same number of 0's given that `start.time = 9`

Anyone knows what's going on here?

I think we (@jogo) found the problem here.

```
> dput(start.time)
8.99999999999818
>
```

Comment: Please give us the result of `dput(start.time)`, i.e. edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42482993/edit

Comment: so `start.time` is less than 9. It is truncated to 8 during coercion to integer (for use in `rep()`)

Comment: The problem was found in there. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @jogo, do you reckon I ought to delete the post?

Comment: Just closing as dupe is fine.